# Laravel migration fails on passport install

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm having problems with a bit complex migration in laravel.
Namely, on passport installation, I'm getting an error that says:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete
> or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (Connection:
> forum, SQL: drop table if exists `categories`)

What could be the problem here? I'm disabling foreign keys, and still getting it:

```
return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::connection('forum')->create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('color')->nullable();
            $table->json('title');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('parent_id')->nullable();
            $table->json('slug');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('image_id');
            $table->json('short_description')->nullable()->comment('description showed in a list');
            $table->json('long_description')->nullable()->comment('description showed in category page');
            $table->boolean('is_locked');
            $table->double('order');
            $table->string('url_link')->nullable()->comment('if category is registered as third-party link');

            $table->foreign('image_id')->references('id')->on(new Expression(env('DB_DATABASE').'.icon_or_image'))->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreignUuid('web_id')->references('id')->on(new Expression(env('DB_DATABASE_WEBSITES').'.websites'))->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::connection('forum')->create('threads', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->enum('status', ['open', 'closed', 'restricted'])->default('open');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->longText('description');

            $table->foreignUuid('web_id')->references('id')->on(new Expression(env('DB_DATABASE_WEBSITES').'.websites'))->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreignUuid('user_id')->references('id')->on(new Expression(env('DB_DATABASE').'.users'))->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->dateTime('interacted_at')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::connection('forum')->create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->longText('description');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('replied_to')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('thread_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');

            $table->foreign('replied_to')->references('id')->on('posts')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreignUuid('web_id')->references('id')->on(new Expression(env('DB_DATABASE_WEBSITES').'.websites'))->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreignUuid('user_id')->references('id')->on(new Expression(env('DB_DATABASE').'.users'))->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('thread_id')->references('id')->on('threads')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::connection('forum')->create('user_interactions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignUuid('web_id')->references('id')->on(new Expression(env('DB_DATABASE_WEBSITES').'.websites'))->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');
            $table->foreignUuid('user_id')->references('id')->on(new Expression(env('DB_DATABASE').'.users'))->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->uuidMorphs('interaction');

            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::connection('forum')->create('category_statistics', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('last_interaction')->nullable();
//            $table->unsignedBigInteger('last_thread_id')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');
            $table->bigInteger('threads_count')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('posts_count')->default(0);
//            $table->dateTime('last_post_time')->nullable();
//            $table->dateTime('last_thread_time')->nullable();

            $table->foreign('last_interaction')->references('id')->on('user_interactions');
//            $table->foreign('last_thread_id')->references('id')->on('threads');
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::connection('forum')->create('thread_views', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('thread_id');
            $table->integer('sessions')->default(0);
            $table->foreignUuid('web_id')->references('id')->on(new Expression(env('DB_DATABASE_WEBSITES').'.websites'))->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('thread_id')->references('id')->on('threads')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreignUuid('device_id')->references('id')->on(new Expression(env('DB_DATABASE').'.devices'))->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });

        Schema::connection('forum')->create('thread_votes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedInteger('vote');
            $this->extracted($table,'threads');
        });

        Schema::connection('forum')->create('thread_reactions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('emoji');
            $this->extracted($table, 'threads');
        });

        Schema::connection('forum')->create('post_reactions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('emoji');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('post_id');

            $table->foreignUuid('web_id')->references('id')->on(new Expression(env('DB_DATABASE_WEBSITES').'.websites'))->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreignUuid('user_id')->references('id')->on(new Expression(env('DB_DATABASE').'.users'))->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();
        Schema::connection('forum')->dropIfExists('categories');
        Schema::connection('forum')->dropIfExists('threads');
        Schema::connection('forum')->dropIfExists('posts');
        Schema::connection('forum')->dropIfExists('category_statistics');
        Schema::connection('forum')->drop('thread_views');
        Schema::connection('forum')->drop('thread_votes');
        Schema::connection('forum')->drop('thread_reactions');
        Schema::connection('forum')->drop('post_reactions');
        Schema::connection('forum')->drop('user_interactions');

        Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
    }

    public function extracted(Blueprint $table, string $table_name): void
    {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger($table_name . '_id');
        $table->foreignUuid('web_id')->references('id')->on(new Expression(env('DB_DATABASE_WEBSITES').'.websites'))->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign($table_name . '_id')->references('id')->on('threads')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreignUuid('user_id')->references('id')->on(new Expression(env('DB_DATABASE').'.users'))->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    }
};
```

Comment: the only thing i see is the `down` side (since it is the only thing doing any `drop`s)  ... your `down`  would have to undo what the `up` was doing .... which means things would be undone in reverse order ... you can't drop the first table you created when a table that was created after that relies on it (related; foreign key) .... why is `down` being called if you are trying to install a package's migration?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what should I do here

Comment: i am not sure why you are rolling back but you would need your `down` to drop the tables in the reverse order in which you created them

Answer (score 0):

Because there are records in other tables where category_id of them is referencing to the value of ids in categories table. Try moving Schema::connection('forum')->dropIfExists('categories') to a lower position

```
    public function down()
    {
         Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();
         Schema::connection('forum')->drop('thread_views');
         Schema::connection('forum')->drop('thread_votes');
         Schema::connection('forum')->drop('thread_reactions');
         Schema::connection('forum')->drop('post_reactions');
         Schema::connection('forum')->drop('user_interactions');
         Schema::connection('forum')->dropIfExists('posts');
         Schema::connection('forum')->dropIfExists('threads');
         Schema::connection('forum')->dropIfExists('category_statistics');
         Schema::connection('forum')->dropIfExists('categories');
    
         Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
    }
```

Comment: It's still the same :/

Comment: I edited my answer. Make sure you drop tables having foreign ids before

Comment: I have added now everywhere dropIfExists, not it's failing on user_interactions :/ Maybe because it's related to the previous ones

Comment: So it's ok now?

Comment: I found the right order, thank you <3